# Real Time Audio Visualization Java

Tags: java, audio, visualization

I have built an application using Java Sound API which enables to record and play the voice and the program shows a wave form of the recorded voice after the recording is finished. I want to show the wave form at the same time when the recording is done. Can anyone suggest a method or a java library to achieve this?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Andrew: I would guess that the OP really means "while recording."

Comment: Thanks Andrew and Matt. Yes, real time means at the time the recording is done. The program should show a waveform or something once it get a voice from the microphone.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Processing](http://www.processing.org/) for your visualization. It does a good job of visualizing realtime data. Write your analyzer using Java Sound API to process the audio input in real time, and draw the visualization using processing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer bconneen.I have never used Processing before. I will give it a try.

Comment: Can you tell me a way to process the audio in real time? I have written it to draw the waveform after the recording is finished. Can I use a buffer? Please give me an idea.

Comment: I'd suggest [this](http://anthonymattox.com/visualizing-sound-with-processing) would be a good place to start.